# show Record in Data Grid View Through a Rolln Number

Tags: vb.net

I want to show only one record in my DataGridView in vb.net with the following code but it is not still working.

```
Dim itm As Integer
itm = InputBox("Enter Roll no of student")
Dim t As New DataTable
Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = Nothing
Dim tuser As String = itm
If objCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
    objCon.ConnectionString = strConnection
    objCon.Open()
End If
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM testsession WHERE ROLLNUMBER=" & itm
Try
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, objCon)
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read
        MessageBox.Show(reader.GetString(0).ToString & _
                        vbTab & vbTab & reader.GetString(1).ToString)
    End While
Finally
    If reader IsNot Nothing Then reader.Close()
End Try
```

Here `testsession` is my table name and `rollnumber` is a primary key through which I search.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dt As New DataTable, itm = InputBox("Enter Roll no of student",, "0")

Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM testsession WHERE ROLLNUMBER=" & itm, strConnection)
    da.Fill(dt)
End Using

Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt ' change DataGridView1 to the name of your DataGridView
```